# I am trying to show the only link of the button which is clicked, so which button is clicked it will show the link of that button down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flask

Here is my code: When I click on one button, it hide all links. And show on one button also. Links and titles are lists which change their lengths in python. I want to show the link of only button which is clicked not all. I have also tried using div but also same problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Python Jobs</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">
  <section class="hero is-dark is-bold">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <p class="title">
      Job Title
    </p>
    <p class="subtitle">
      Python jobs
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("a").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("a").show();
  });
})
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      {% for i in range(0, len-1) %}
        <h3>{{i+1}}. {{title[i]}}</h3>
          <a href={{links[i]}}>{{links[i]}}</a>
          <button id="show">Show</button>
          <button id="hide"> Hide</button>
        <br>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs have to unique. `id="show"` and `id="hide"` aren't unique.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problem in your code.

1. id must be unique so use class instead of id.
2. Wrap your each heading and link with container. In your case move your div inside for loop.
3. Based upon your  button click find your heading and link to show / hide.
4. Initially hide your  heading and link (It's depend upon your logic, how you want to present UI)

Example:

```js
$(".hide").click(function() {
  $(this).parent('div').find('a ,h3').hide();
});
$(".show").click(function() {
  $(this).parent('div').find('a ,h3').show();
});
```

```css
a,
h3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Title1</h3>
  <a href="link1">Link1</a>
  <button class="show">Show</button>
  <button class="hide"> Hide</button>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Title2</h3>
  <a href="link1">Link2</a>
  <button class="show">Show</button>
  <button class="hide"> Hide</button>

</div>
```